# Bind Server issue: Can not nslookup from client when DNS Master is down, but still can connect to Internet

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nslookup

I setup 2 Bind servers on Ubuntu Server 14.04. The first one is Master DNS and the second is Slave. I have a DHCP server running isc-dhcp-server and assign 2 DNS Server IP for clients

Everything seem working good but just one thing that is not what i want is when i try to shutdown the Master DNS server then i try to nslookup on client and what i get is:

> DNS request timed out.
>
> timeout was 2 seconds.
>
> Default Server:  UnKnown
>
> Address:  My_MasterDNS_IP

**Note: Client can't nslookup but Client can connect to the internet and surfing  web OK**

What i think is when the Master DNS down then the Slave DNS server must be replace and response to the client nslookup but it's not.

So do i have to configure anything special on my 2 DNS Server or what i thing is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The file `/etc/resolv.conf` should contain a `nameserver` record for each name server you want to use.  Normally, they will be used in order but there is `rotate` option that can be set.  If having the master down causes resolution to fail, either the slave is not listed or is not reachable.  Check man `resolv.conf` for more details.

You may have the `resolvconf` utility installed which will rebuild the `/etc/resolv.conf` as interfaces change.  It has its own man page.

Comment: in my /etc/resolv.conf contain two nameserver record (the Master and the Slave) on both DNS Server. 
So you mean i have to use the rotate option for what i want to be done ?

Answer (score 0):

What type of nslookup didn't work, for local zones, are you using the server for caching also, do you use some forwarder for the rest of the zones or you are using the **roots**?

Comment: i mean nslookup didn't work not just the local zones but the other too.

Comment: Did you try nslookup directly to the secondary server skipping the `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: Yes, i already have by set the Secondary Server as a Primary DNS on client device, and it's working fine